# MySQL Indexes creation

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms, indexing, database-optimization

I have a table with 10 columns and I need to support combined range filters for most of them.

Let's say for example:

```
WHERE column_a >= a_min AND column_a <= a_max 
AND column_b >= b_min AND column_b <= b_max
...
```

But that is not all, I need also to support sorting data by different columns.

My question is, considering that the possible indexes combinations to create in order to optimize the searches is huge, which are my possible options?

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing you can do - is to create N single indexes (1 per column). Don't put this an answer because curious if any alternatives

Comment: @sebasuy, how many rows are you expecting your table to hold? For relatively small tables, performance may actually be better when scanning the table rather than accessing via an index.

Comment: @Mark, the table will have many records, I estimate between 6 and 10 million. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create indexes for each of the columns individually. Let mysql figure out how to use them.

Also, on a side note, get in the habit of using the `between` operator:

```
column_a between a_min AND a_max
```

rather than:

```
column_a >= a_min AND column_a <= a_max -- ugly and the semantic is not as obvious
```

It's easier to read and type and does *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: +1, but have to disagree with your comment about 'BETWEEN', for me, '=>' AND '<=' is more explicit than 'BETWEEN'. (I doubt any one has asked SO the question does >= AND <= include range boundaries)

Comment: I agree with Kevin, it's more explicit. Thanks for your answer, +1.

Comment: I didn't know this "between" operator I'm really glad you've mentioned it !

Answer (score 0):

create an index for all the columns used in the query.

(column_a, column_n)

See The Range Access Method for Multiple-Part Indexes here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/range-optimization.html

Comment: As long as he has not-equality comparisons with all fields - according to the link you've given the composite index **will not work** (or to be precise - only first column of index will be used)